# MTG Arena: Current shuffler (and matchmaker) functionality and rules

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

**Bit on a rant intro, not necessary to understand the question.** There is a heated debate between Arena players if (not) is the card shuffler (and matchmaker) rigged. I myself experienced very strange phenomenon. When I played on my PC, I was getting very poor draws with my Mono Red Deck and my win ratio was around 55%. However, when I swapped to playing on my laptop (first&new installation, this time not through Epic, but directly through WotC) I was getting incredibly lucky draws for roughly 50+ games easily getting 85% win ratio, most of the time being on the play and I would say getting favorable match-ups. I'm pretty sure about the win ratios and the quality of the hands (I used a tracker), the rest can really be my perspective. Anyways, I did not put too much thought into it back then.

**Important part:** However, today I came across this post about [lands in the opening hand](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/how-do-i-tune-my-magic-arena-mtga-deck-for-3-lands-in-my-opening-hand-under-t?rq=1). Also this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/comments/b21u3n/i_analyzed_shuffling_in_a_million_games/) post shows pretty thoroughly that the shuffler is not really random. I went and read some WotC forum posts and found people claiming that match maker altered their opponent picks according to their win ratio, providing (alleged) stats from trackers.

I'm okay with the shuffler and potentially matchmaker being 'rigged', to provide better game experience but only as long as the functionality is clear and public. **Does anyone know of verified, up-to-date source which describes the shuffler and matchmaker rules, so one can play around it?** *So far I found nothing except small pieces of potentially outdated info or unfounded theories.*

---

EDIT: I wonder if it was all my poor explanation or also people skim reading too much and ignoring comments but **I intended this question purely as a search for information behind the shuffler/matchmaker**. I think this is **NOT** opinion based and it feels to me that many people when see thread discussing shuffler/matchmaker automatically presume it is just salt mine thread, hence the vote for closing the question for being 'opinion based'. Anyways to sump up what I learned so far from comments and otherwise are:

- Every time you shuffle in BO1, shuffle is done twice and the hand with the number of lands more representing the actual ratio of lands in your deck is chosen as your hand. This means it is extremely good to mulligan. This is very helpful to me because I avoided mulligan a lot in a fear of getting hand without lands or flooded by them, playing sub-optimal hands.
- Fisher Yates is used for permutations. I also read Mersenne Twister is somehow involved, maybe for picking up the random numbers in Fisher Yates. Even though Mersenne Twister is not really very good at being random, I guess it is sufficient for this but I wonder if choosing a seed which would be unique for each id could somehow lead into what I experience. Anyway this is just a thought.
- As for a matchmaker the only thing I noticed myself and also picked up from the threads I skimmed over and I'm confident enough to call without statistics is **mirroring**. You will face mirrors of your deck more often then it is represented in meta and people like CovertGoBlue who plays MTGA every day for hours claims to see this empirically too.
- **The following IS ONLY MY OBSERVATION but as this question is being voted to be closed as opinion based I think I will plug this in.** I feel that MTGA deliberately 'tests' your deck. BTW I don't consider this to be a bad thing. I feel like it happens more than often that when picking new deck or running streak of wins or losses I run into very obscure cards which are either intended as a counters or a very favorable match-ups for me. I played Gruul yesterday running into mirrors, green, rogues, white aggro, black control, 0 Dimir's control. As soon as I switched to Cycling I get [Ashiok's Erasure](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=476294), which just shuts cycling with its little variability of cards which you actually play and who even plays this card anymore, and Dimir's control against. Like camaaan. :D I'm okay with it, but if this is random then what are the odds. There are many other theories and I don't want to be too much of a tin foil hatter but the only thing I'm trying to say here is: ***I do think that some meta table similar to [this one](https://mtgmeta.io/metagame) but much more detailed, maybe even for specific cards, pair of cards or something is actually being built behind the scenes and it is somehow used to balance the gameplay further than just giving you mirrors more often. And again, I don't mind. Making the experience more balanced **IS GOOD** but I'm only trying to figure out its inner workings to understand if you should play more focused decks or more broad ones and so on.***

Comment: This is how randomness works. Random does _not_ mean "evenly distributed", until you have thousands or even millions of events. Humans are inherently bad at coping with the mercilessness of random, and believe we see patterns and intents everywhere. It is why we have prayed to weather gods for millennia, and it is most likely why you believe the shuffler to be rigged.

Comment: @Arthur, your point is most apt.  However, there are often bugs in software.  There was a bug in the random number generator for Ultima Online that went undetected for YEARS, with many players discussing how to take advantage of it...  It was very tricky to set up, but once you did, you could "farm" incredibly successfully.  eXPRESS doesn't provide enough information to indicate if this is real, but 50 games at 85% winrate and 50 (??) games at 55% win rate is statistically significant.

Comment: @Arthur I mention my situation only as an example. It is clear from the posts I provided that the generation is not purely random, at least not in the sense of drawing one hand of 7 cards from the deck. I don't have the problem with it being so, I actually prefer ideas like in the first post when multiple hands are shuffled and the one more representing your deck is selected. In fact I find that idea to be genius. The only problem I have with it is that it is not public knowledge hence I'm trying to find a source to understand the mechanism. Same goes for the matchmaker and endless mirroring.

Comment: @John Sorry, I do believe it was roughly 40-60 games, but I reset the stats on my PC so I can't be sure. I also understand that someone 'has to win the lottery' since there are lot of players playing and it might have been me who struck lucky on my laptop while unlucky on my PC.

Comment: @Arthur not really, they've actually outright said that their code doesn't intend true randomness, but does actually have code intended to smooth out card distribution between land and non-land. It still randomizes but lets call it random with an intentional bias to certain states.

Comment: @Andrew I know that skewing randomness to placate players is a thing in game design. I didn't know Arena had bowed to the pressure.

Comment: @Arthur I would not use the term 'bow to the pressure' here as most of the players actually call for the 'true randomness' even though they don't realize, it might be worse still. The only problem I see is that the system is a closed box which makes it unfair to people who expect no bias, because the rules were not clearly stated otherwise.

Comment: @Arthur behind the scenes it shuffles and draws twice then discards the less balanced hand of the two (based on the algorithm's idea of balance) they talked about it officially via forum announcement here:  https://forums.mtgarena.com/forums/threads/26319?page=1

Comment: It's entirely plausible that Arena's matchmaking and shuffling aren't uniformly random, either by accident or by design. However, it is *extremely* unlikely that your switch from PC to laptop has anything to do with it, because there is no good reason the accident or the design would take your platform into account.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Yeah, you are right. I only wanted to add the motivation from my own experience and why I started to research this in a first place. I realize I poorly formatted my question and it led to a confusion. What I actually care about is the research behind how the shuffler/matchmaker works because it is not purely random and I want to understand it to leverage it as much as possible. Anyway in my example I don't think it would be because of change of the hardware/platform but rather to simply motivate new players to stay with the game by winning more. I'm not accusing them of it btw.

Comment: @Andrew It's worth noting the "smoothing" shuffler applies only to Bo1; Bo3 matches just do one draw and use that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall fair, but bo1 matches are, i belive, still the vast majority of games played on MTGa. I dont even build sideboards for most decks unless they use fae of wishes or similar.

Comment: You guys get all hung up about anecdotal desktop vs. laptop statistics, but you forget that each game, in its entirety (in particular shuffling), happens on the *remote MTGA server*, not on anyone's client. What insanity can lead anyone to believe that the server decides to favor players based on the platform they're playing on? I'm well aware MTGA has quite the history with bugs, but a correct shuffling algorithm is really trivial (google Fisher Yates), and would thus require extra effort to get wrong, especially in such a significant and easily detectable way. The whole premise is hogwash.

Comment: @Hackworth You are right, I just want to stress once more that my question was NOT about the example I gave even though many decided to make it the center piece of the question even though I specifically tried to state that it is not the case. The thought behind the example, if there was any, wasn't about actual hardware but more about letting new players win more often POSSIBLY. If we consider that the log and all statistics are empty on new machine, which they are, this can be checked by downloading a tracker which uses them.

Comment: @eXPRESS "The stats are from Plat to Mythic. The laptop was only Diamond+" It doesn't matter that you're a new player, you're playing a competitive ladder and are in the top half of it - the higher you go on the ladder, the better your opponents who also made that climb will be.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, the reason I mentioned it is the Event factor mentioned by John in the answer below. It would work in exactly reversed logic in my case, having higher win ratio against better opponents. It could have been negated by me understanding the deck more tho. Who knows, but once I will have more time I'm thinking I will maybe post a constructive question about inner workings of matchmaker/shuffler on WotC forums and try to get some upvotes to mb get a reaction from devs. Maybe if asked in civilized manner without crying about it being unfair, I get something and can post it here then.

Comment: @eXPRESS quite honestly, since its about black box code for matchmaking and shuffling in the digital game, its not likely we can say more than we already have, we all only know whats been publicised.

Comment: @Andrew I know I meant I will post it on WotC as a question for the developers of the game.

Answer (score 4):

On the surface, 85% win rate over 50 games compared to 55% win rate over (??) games is statistically significant.

But, the danger of doing a single variate statistical analysis (which is rampant in modern discourse) is you aren't examining investigating other potential causes.

For Arena, specifically, I have found the following to have significant impact in my win rates.

- Time of day.  In my time zone, if I play between 10 am and 3 pm my win rates are significantly higher than if I play between 5 pm and 10 pm.
- Event.  You haven't indicated event.  If I am on the "play" queue, I often win at much  higher rates than if I'm on the "standard ranked" queue.  I suspect other events have similarly higher variability.
- Rank:  My win rates in gold on the Best of 1 ladder are vastly higher than my win rates in Platinum.
- Play Queue:  My son likes brewing decks and playing on the play queue.  His win rate is very low (he is a fan of jank) if he plays a lot, and I start playing on the play queue, I win all the time.
- The Selection Effect: (Credit to Phillip Kendall) No one posts if they change computers and see no impact.  In [2019 there were 3 million active players of Arena](https://dotesports.com/mtg/news/mtg-continues-to-make-millions-for-hasbro#:%7E:text=With%20a%20reported%20three%20million,brand%20(tabletop%20and%20digital).), the probably that at least one of them changes computers and saw variations of this size is non-trivial
  .

I'm sure I've missed others.

Comment: The biggest thing you've missed is the selection effect. Nobody posts when they charge machine and their win rate doesn't change, only if it does.

Comment: I don't play queue, only ranked, so the variability should be low. The stats are from Plat to Mythic. The laptop was only Diamond+ so that should also mean lower win ratio as people are generally better. I wonder how time of the day could make the difference, I did not see any effect on my win ratio but it is definitely interesting observation. To the Sel. Eff., not only that the person must change the computer but also observe this by playing long in a row and if this applies only to new players to boost their ego it might be unnoticeable. Also they have to care to mention and you notice it.

Comment: Follow up, I don't make any accusations about WotC, I just think that noticing such a thing could really be tricky as we can be talking about very small fraction of a percent of players to be able to experience it let alone notice it, report it and the statement to reach the reader without getting lost. Also the posts are provided show it is not random per say, drawing 7 cards from a deck once, I'm okay with that, I really just want to know exactly how the mechanism works so I can better hedge my odds when mulligan, creating very specific deck or countering meta decks.

Comment: @eXPRESS, there are two issues here.  1.  Win percentage based on hardware.  2. How does the "land smoothing" algoritohm affect gameplay.  My answer addresses the first issue.  That issue is completely independent of the second, as it affects both game players equally.  If you have a specific question on 2. ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @John Sure, but does it though. At least the things you mentioned does not seem to have effect on the stats I acquired. I think that my measurements are most likely just result of pseudo-random luck and my initial intention was not to claim otherwise. The reason why I mentioned it in a first place was only to provide the context why I started to dig into this. My question is actually about point 2 all along, but not only about land smoothing but generally about rules used in the shuffler/matchmaker. I see now that I maybe did not make myself entirely clear, so I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @eXPRESS time of day makes a difference because it changes the location most players are from, and potentially the meta they build for locally is different than the meta you built for (This is less of a thing now that people aren't playing with in person local metas as much as online global, but Time of Day still keeps it alive to a degree) The meta here in North America may be different than the meta in Europe which may not match the meta in Japan.

Comment: @Andrew You are right but especially in higher ranks most of the people just netdeck and make little tweaks to stay competitive. In my experience, which granted is not big, I did not notice change between playing in the morning opposite to evening and so on. Funnily enough what I noticed though is that once CGB (CovertGoBlue) publishes a deck on yt, next day it is all over the place. :D